# Is an output noise in the micro range any good?

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-noise-amplifier

I have designed the below circuit, as mentioned in the previous post the input is a 50mV RMS @ 50Hz signal, the bandwidth is 1kHz, and the output amplifies this by 20V/V.

[image]

I have seen people do a noise simulation when trying to design LNA. Below is a snippet of this amplifier:

[image]

The noise taken from Vout is shown below.

[image]

My question is:

1. What information does this noise simulation and how can I use it practically?
2. Is this noise output good when compared to other LNAs?

Comment: Noise simulation is the simulation of the noise generated by the devices (e.g. resistors and transistors) in your circuit. You can further divide the noise by the gain to get the input-referred noise and compare this with other designs, or even integrate it to get a rms noise voltage (you may want to see more details in an analog circuit design textbook). In your case the noise generated by the device is small enough, but if you are building a PCB the noise generated by the power line coupling could be a real problem.

Comment: Is R3 a sensor for current? After running noise analysis, click on R3 to see how much of V(onoise) is due to R3. I think you'll be disappointed. A really low-noise LNA contributes little excess noise above noise that source resistance contributes. Is a power-line environment inherently low noise? I'd suggest that noise floor might be higher than that set by R3, even if you take great care routing signals to your amplifier.